# installing ubuntu 22.04 into existing lvm

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, installation

I installed kubuntu 22.04 onto fresh machine. It turns out, that its "quirks and features" blocks my workflow, and I need to go away from KDE. But it would be ideal for me, if I could keep existing system working until new one is ready, and install new one aside.

I use LVM over crypted partition. So I made free space in respective volume group. I'm relatively new to ubuntu and I'm not that aware of its installers and its behavior. Can someone advise, how to install into existing lvm on crypted partition without losing previous data? I used to do this in fedoras installer, and it was always extreme pain due to it's unique layout and behavior.

I guess:

1. backup data
2. decrypt partition using `cryptsetup luksOpen what whereTo`
3. load lvm using vgScan
4. ??? what next? Will installer lead me through logical volume creation process, or shall I create them beforehand and then select them in installer somehow? Is there some gotcha to be aware of?

sorry for asking trivial/asking about unknown question, but I'd like not to step on some unknown rake, as this is the first time I'm doing it on ubuntu ...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, KUbuntu and Ubuntu differ only in pre-install package groups, to the best of my knowledge. You should only remove `kde-desktop` package and install a DE of your choice suitable to your workflow.

Comment: thanks for comment. I don't think this is correct, as reading keyboard behaves very differently in kde and non-kde spins. And even if you are correct and this could be done, this does not answer the question (to maybe not best approach), how to install into existing lvm. But again, thank for trying to help me!